# New Google Signin (Web) doesn't work in Firefox Dev Edition

Tags: firefox, google-signin, firefox-developer-edition

I am facing this weird error where Firefox Dev edition would just not get the google signin script. It works in Chrome but not in Firefox.

I am using the same javascript as shown in the [google signin documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

Interestingly, if I use an older version of the javascript (from cached page), it works in Firefox dev edition.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" async defer></script>
```

Does anyone have a clue about what's going on? Because I don't!

Comment: What do you mean when saying you use an 'older version of the JavaScript (from cached page)'? Can you visit the https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js directly without any problems?

Comment: An older version of the gogle signin documentation in google search cache, had the client: prefix. I was able to get both versions in Firefox directly but the browser won't fetch platform.js when it was in a script tag in <head>. Now I'm using client:platform.js which works.